# Нужно из базы данных выводить значение ключа по id

Tags: php, база-данных, pdo

Всем привет.

Подскажите, плиз, ответ на задачку. Нужно из базы данных выводить значение ключа по id, но так, чтобы вставлять потом разные значения в разные места, и id уже заменять цифрой в конкретном месте html кода `id= '3';`

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=comments', 'root', '');
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT output FROM class_output WHERE id = '$id'");
$query->execute();

$com = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($com as $value){
    echo $value['output'] ;
}
```

Comment: а разве в любом учебнике по php не написано это?

Comment: Да я, в принципе, по учебникам и учусь, только не выводится, хоть убей...

Comment: `SELECT id, output`. А текущий код с постановкой значения прямо в строку небезопасен, не делайте так.

Comment: Это чисто вывод данных из БД, там будет всего несколько пунктов, занесённых вручную

Comment: Что никоим образом не меняет ситуацию с безопасностью, у вас через этот пример могут грохнуть вообще всё или загрузить чего угодно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, учту

Comment: Когда пойму каким образом это смогут сделать... Из БД идёт только выгрузка контента, записи в неё нет.  Как по примеру смогут грохнуть баз?, Я не стебусь, просто реально новичок и не понимаю... Если не трудно, то объясните, если долго писать, тоне надо, пойму..